# What is best practice to store user data?

Tags: sql, database

I know this is a really basic question yet I did not find further information. Figure I want to develop a basic multiple-user application for notes. In my database I have a table where I store user IDs, usernames and passwords.

I now want to store the users notes, but a user should only be able to see their **own** notes. What is best practice to do this? The two possibilities that come to my mind are

1. Create a table for each user where you store their notes (probably
   scales horribly bad)
2. Have one big notes-table and save the user IDs as secondary keys (It just
   feels a bit "off" to have everything stored in one big table)

Is one of these two ideas used in this exact way in large scale real-world projects? If so, is there anything else one has to pay attention to?

Comment: go for second options, even you can store notes in the user table that you already have. just add new column

Comment: *I have a table where I store user IDs, usernames and passwords* Never store passwords in a database, instead store password hashes.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to abstract it a bit, in a real world example I would of course store the hashes only. It just feels counter-intuitive to have all the data in one big table, even though this seems the way to go

Comment: Research the design principles of relational database normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need the 2nd option.
My advice to you, please don’t create any auth functions, because it's a very hard solution for the beginners. Much better for this type of application (as notes) is to use a serverless architecture.

E.g. Firebase, Supabase and so on.

Where you will have database, security authentication, record level security, storage for files etc.